# Calculate running total of multiple values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sum multiple values, e.g.

- `[4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0]`
- `[3333.444, 0, 1123.44, 5444]`
- `[321112.4, 443.3, 0, 4444]`

I was thinking of a loop, but I don't know how to proceed:

```
values = []

(0..3).each do |value|
  # values << [4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0]       on 1st iteration
  # values << [3333.444, 0, 1123.44, 5444]   on 2nd iteration
  # values << [321112.4, 443.3, 0, 4444]     on 3rd iteration

  # Here I need to add each array with the next one
end
```

The result would be `[324890.174, 443.3, 1456.884, 9888]`

Comment: Your example has nested arrays. Do you want to flatten it and then add or add all separately?

Comment: I don't want to flatten it because as I said in the above example I want to add the first element of the first array and the first element of second array like that for all the four sets. So I want to do it separately.

Comment: It was created by myself because you would get  an idea, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the code you posted: You are populating `values` with 12 elements, which are also arrays of 4 elements. That's fine.  You get something which can be regarded as a 12x4 matrix. Then what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Amal regarding your edit: in your actual code, do you have a nested array (or matrix) whose "columns" you want to sum? Or do you want to sum one "row" at a time, something like a [running total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total)?

Comment: @Stefan exactly that's what I was trying to say like a running total.

Comment: Amal, when you are asked to clarify your question you should edit your question rather than answering with comments. Questions should stand on their own, in part because readers should not be expected to read through all the comments to figure out the question. When you edit the question just do it like you are editing a paper. Don't write, for example, "EDIT:".

Comment: @Amal I think I get it now. Where do the values / rows come from that you want to sum? And do you want to do anything else with each row beside adding its values to the running total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE1:
it doesn't change anything.
You can still apply the codes.

```
(0..3).each do |value|
  # First loop 
    values << [4444.33,0,333.444,0]
  # Second loop 
    values << [3333.444,0,1123.44,5444]
  # Third loop
    values << [321112.4,443.3,0,4444] 
  # Here I need to add each array with the next one
    values.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(0, :+)}
end
```

1st ANSWER:
use [mapping](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map). just one line.

```
values.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(0, :+)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a constant length of sub-arrays in the initial array you can use [Array#Transpose](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/transpose) and then sum each resulting array.

For Rails

```
values.transpose.map(&:sum)
```

Or, in plain ruby in case you are in a ruby version older than 2.4 (thanks to Sebastian Palma)

```
values.transpose.map {|x| x.inject(:+) }
```

Comment: I think you want to remove, "For Rails". With `inject` it's generally best to add an initial value of zero in case the array being summed is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add the first element of the first array and the first element of second array like that for all the four sets [...]  like a running total

To get a running total, you could start by creating an empty "totals" array of the correct size:

```
totals = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Adding a row means adding each of row's values to its corresponding total.

This can be done in many ways, for example manually:

```
row = [4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0]

totals[0] += row[0]
totals[1] += row[1]
totals[2] += row[2]
totals[3] += row[3]

p totals #=> [4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0]
```

or via [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) on the row:

```
row = [3333.444, 0, 1123.44, 5444]

row.each_with_index { |v, i| totals[i] += v }

p totals #=> [7777.773999999999, 0, 1456.884, 5444]
```

or via [`map!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) (note the `!`) and [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) on the `totals` array:

```
row = [321112.4, 443.3, 0, 4444]

totals.map!.with_index { |t, i| t + row[i] }

p totals #=> [328890.174, 443.3, 1456.884, 9888]
```

Answer (score 0):

1st ANSWER:

`values.transpose.map(&:sum)`

UPDATE

`values.map.with_index {|v, i| i > 1 ? [*v, values.dig(0, 0), values.dig(1, 0)] : v}`

Comment: You don't need "1st answer" and "Update". Just edit silently, giving one or both approaches. IMO, #2 dilutes a nice clean answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply a row vector of one's with the array converted to a matrix and then convert the result back to an array of sums.

```
values = [
  [  4444.33,    0,    333.444,    0],
  [  3333.444,   0,   1123.44,  5444],
  [321112.4,   443.3,    0,     4444]
]
```

```
require 'matrix'

(Matrix.row_vector([1]*values.size) * Matrix[*values]).to_a.flatten
 => [328890.174, 443.3, 1456.884, 9888]
```

See [Matrix::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [Matrix::row_vector](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-row_vector).

Note:

```
a = Matrix.row_vector([1]*values.size)
  #=> Matrix[[1, 1, 1]] 
b = Matrix[*values]
  #=> Matrix[[4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0],
  #          [3333.444, 0, 1123.44, 5444],
  #          [321112.4, 443.3, 0, 4444]] 
a*b
  #=> Matrix[[328890.174, 443.3, 1456.884, 9888]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents using [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-zip), just if they are already stored in variables:

```
a = [4444.33, 0, 333.444, 0]
b = [3333.444, 0, 1123.44, 5444]
c = [321112.4, 443.3, 0, 4444]

a.zip(b, c).map &:sum
#=> [324890.174, 443.3, 1456.884, 9888]
```

Otherwise:

```
values = [a, b, c]
values.inject([0,0,0,0]) { |acc, e| acc.zip(e).map &:sum }
```

But transpose then map to sum is a cleaner way.